# How to find the branch of a particular trunk folder in svn and vice-a-versa?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to one project which contains branches for trunk folders. I want to find what branches does the specific trunk folder has. 
I have developed a code and now i want to check-in it into svn. But instead of creating a new branch i want to check-in it into one of its existing branch. So how can i find branches of that particular trunk folder and how can i find trunk folder a branch pointing to. 
I thing there could be a property which will help me to find this, but i am not able to find it. For version control we use TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoisSVN has a tool called `Revision Grap` which shows all relationships. You can find it in context menue. By the way: there should be only one trunk in a svn-project.

Comment: Didn't found any relationship in Revision Graph. Yup a svn-project should have only one trunk, here i mean a folder inside trunk.

Comment: So you should talk to the people who create the branches how they have done it. If they used the SVN-branch-commant and if your branch is a real branch (in tearms of svn) than there should be something in the graph.

Comment: _Asking the guys who created it_ option still open, but i wanted a way to find it on my own.

Comment: Found it in revision graph now. Previously i was checking branch which wasn't a branch at all, i was told it's a branch but it isn't. Now i checked other branches in Revision Graph and it's showing relationship with respective trunk folder. Cheers!!

Comment: Nice to here :-). Thanks for upvote and accepting. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Branching of subtree only is (in common) Bad Idea (tm)
2. I can't recall GUI-way for this task, but in CLI you with `>svn log -q -v --stop-on-copy URL/OF/BRANCH` (for every branch) you can find in oldest log record source path in thunk of branch-files

**Note**

For SVN 1.8+ `svn log -q -v ROOT/OF/REPO --search FOLDERNAME` may be nicer (and shorter) solution

```
>svn log ...
...
Changed paths:
   A /tags/1.0.1 (from /trunk:6)
```

where second field in filelist is TARGET, third is SOURCE of `svn cp` operation, used behind the scene (*if used*)

Comment: I tried below command,
**C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin>TortoiseProc.exe /command:log -q -v --stop-on-copy http://apacsvn.barcapint.com/SVNMyProject/repos/MyProjects/Project1/branches/collections**
And got a pop-up window saying,
**Neither /path nor /pathfile was specified or does not contain a valid path!**

Comment: @DineshM - pure CLI svn will be better and easier (TortoiseSVN since 1.7 have CLI-tools in installer) - TortoiseProc may miss some cli-options

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But i have found a GUI way to do this, Answered by @Micha.